# Transform Array to Object In Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I have the following data being returned from my controller:

```
[
  {
    "date": "2019-12-06",
    "weekday": "Friday",
    "users": 2
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-12-07",
    "weekday": "Saturday",
    "users": 1
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-12-08",
    "weekday": "Sunday",
    "users": 1
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-12-09",
    "weekday": "Monday",
    "users": 1
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-12-10",
    "weekday": "Tuesday",
    "users": 1
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-12-11",
    "weekday": "Wednesday",
    "users": 2
  }
]
```

I want to return this instead:

```
{
    "Sunday": 1,
    "Monday": 1,
    "Tuesday": 1,
    "Wednesday": 2,
    "Thursday": 0,
    "Friday": 2,
    "Saturday": 1
}
```

Where the numbers in the object are the "users" in the previous array, how would I go about this please?

Answer (score 3):

You can use like this

```
$data = collect($data);
$result = $data->pluck('weekday', 'users');
```

Then order as you want

Full solution

```
$data = '[
  {
    "date": "2019-12-06",
    "weekday": "Friday",
    "users": 2
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-12-07",
    "weekday": "Saturday",
    "users": 1
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-12-08",
    "weekday": "Sunday",
    "users": 1
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-12-09",
    "weekday": "Monday",
    "users": 1
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-12-10",
    "weekday": "Tuesday",
    "users": 1
  },
  {
    "date": "2019-12-11",
    "weekday": "Wednesday",
    "users": 2
  }
]';


$data = json_decode($data);
$data = collect($data);
$orders = [
    "Sunday",
    "Monday",
    "Tuesday",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday"
];

$result = new stdClass();
foreach ($orders as $weekday) {
    $result->{$weekday} = $data->where('weekday', $weekday)->first()->users ?? 0;
}

dd($result);
```

result is

[image]

Comment: need to add 'thursday' to it since it didn't exist in the records but is in the desired output

Comment: @lagbox I add full solution as need

Answer (score 0):

You can use collection.

```
$yourArray = json_decode('[
    {
        "date": "2019-12-06",
        "weekday": "Friday",
        "users": 2
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-12-07",
        "weekday": "Saturday",
        "users": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-12-08",
        "weekday": "Sunday",
        "users": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-12-09",
        "weekday": "Monday",
        "users": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-12-10",
        "weekday": "Tuesday",
        "users": 1
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-12-11",
        "weekday": "Wednesday",
        "users": 2
    }
    ]');

$collect = collect($yourArray);
$groupped = $collect->groupBy('weekday');

$daysOfWeek = [];

foreach($groupped as $dayName => $items){
    $daysOfWeek[$dayName] = collect($items)->sum('users');
}

dd($daysOfWeek);
```

Comment: need to add 'thursday' which isnt in the input but is in the desired output